How to find all the queries which are executed on Azure SQL database with username using T-SQL
I have requirement to find all the queries which are executed in last 24 hours on an Azure SQL database with user name. I have got the below query which is giving me all the queries run in last 24 hours but I am unable to get the user information on that, like who has run that query.
I don't have access to the Azure Portal so have to get it from T-SQL.
SELECT 
    Qry.last_execution_time,
    Txt.query_text_id, Txt.query_sql_text, Pl.plan_id,   
    Qry.*, txt.*, pl.*
FROM 
    sys.query_store_plan AS Pl
INNER JOIN 
    sys.query_store_query AS Qry ON Pl.query_id = Qry.query_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.query_store_query_text AS Txt ON Qry.query_text_id = Txt.query_text_id
WHERE
    Qry.last_execution_time >= DATEADD(Day,-1,Getdate())    
ORDER BY
    1 DESC;

I tried below query as well but it is giving me the user name but this showing current running queries not the history
SELECT 
    s.login_name,
    r.command,
    r.status,
    r.start_time,
    r.total_elapsed_time,
    r.cpu_time,
    r.logical_reads,
    r.writes,
    r.reads,
    r.text_size,
    r.statement_start_offset,
    r.statement_end_offset,
    q.text AS [query_text],
    
    r.database_id,
    r.user_id,
    r.blocking_session_id,
    r.wait_type,
    r.wait_time,
    r.last_wait_type
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_requests r
INNER JOIN 
    sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON r.session_id = s.session_id
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS q
WHERE 
    r.start_time >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) -- Queries executed in the last 24 hours
ORDER BY 
    r.start_time DESC;


The query store does not store who ran a query. If you need to store information of who/what is running what queries, you should set up extended events.

Query store and the plan cache are not designed for that type of logging and auditing, they are designed for debugging query plans only. Either set up a SQL Audit or use XEvents.

The best way to have that information is to enable SQL Auditing, then you can query Audit logs as shown below:
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditing -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroup"
 -ServerName "SQL Server Name" -DatabaseName "AdventureWorksLT"  
 -StorageAccountName "storageAccount" 
-AuditActionGroup "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP" 
 -AuditAction "UPDATE ON database::[AdventureWorksLT] BY [public]"  
 -RetentionInDays 60

A sample audit record for the BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP will show the following information:

